# Remote Docker container by hostname

Tags: docker, docker-compose

How do you access remote Docker container by its hostname?

I need to access remote Docker containers by its hostnames (or some constant IP's) for development and testing purposes. I have tried:

- looking for any DNS approach (have not found any clues),
- importing /ets/hosts (probably impossible),
- creating tunnes (only this works but it is very time consuming).

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as running any other process on a host, Docker or not Docker: you access it via the host name or IP address of the host and the port the service is listening on (the first port of the `docker run -p` argument).  Docker containers don't have externally visible individual IP addresses any more than non-Docker HTTP or ssh daemons do.

If you do have DNS infrastructure available to you, you could set up CNAME records to resolve particular service names to the specific hosts that are running them.

One solution that may help you is some sort of service registry; in the past I've used [Consul](https://consul.io/) with some success.  You can configure Consul with some health checks or other probes ("look for an HTTP service on port 12345 that answers GET / calls"), and it will provide its own DNS service ("okay, `http://whatevername.service.consul:12345/` will reach your service on whichever hosts it happens to be running on").

Nothing in the Docker infrastructure specifically helps this.  Using `/etc/hosts` is distinctly not a best practice: the name-to-IP mapping needs to be kept in sync across all machines and you'll start wishing you had a network service to publish it for you, which is exactly what DNS is for.